# Can I Specify an Existing ACL using a Radius AV Pair?

Tags: vpn, cisco, access-control-list, radius

I am able to specify access-lists for VPN users on my IAS radius server using avpairs like:

```
Cisco-AVpair = "ip:outacl[#number]={standard-access-control-list | 
extended-access-control-list}"
```

So for example:

```
ip:inacl#101=deny tcp 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 any eq 21
```

Instead of specifying each line of the ACL, is there a directive that will let me specify that it should use an extended access list that exists in the IOS config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is:

```
ip:inacl=<aclnumber>
```

So for example:

```
ip:inacl=101
```

From what I can tell, extended ACLs work, but named ACLs do not work.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want the filter-id attribute. See http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps6120/products_configuration_example09186a0080a9eddc.shtml#new for details.

Comment: I've found that I can either use filter-id or cisco AV pairs, but not both. At least on the ASA series. Don't know about switches.